# group by conditional presence of 2 values for a field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given a document like this :

```
{

    "identifier" : "1234",
    "year" : 2018,
    "days" : 30
}
```

Where year can have only 2 values : previous year and current year.

When both previous year and current are present in database i need to include only previous year in my group stage.

Here my current query :

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
      {  
         "$match":{  
            "identifier":{  
               "$in":[  
                  "1234",
               ]
            },

         }
      },
      {  
         "$group":{  
            "_id":null,
            "days":{  
              "$sum":"$days"

            }
         }
      }
])
```

Is it possible ? 
Thanks

Comment: Could you show sample documents and expected output ?

Comment: if i have these 2 documents :  {
    "identifier" : "1234",
    "year" : 2018,
    "days" : 30
} and {
    "identifier" : "1234",
    "year" : 2019,
    "days" : 20
} The sum should be 30 because of previous year. If i had only the 2018 the sum should be 30 and if i had only 2019 the sum should be 20

Answer (score 1):

You can [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) by `year` and then take the oldest one ([$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) + [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/index.html))

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {  
       "$match":{  
          "identifier":{  
             "$in":[  
                "1234",
             ]
          }
       }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$year",
            days: { $sum: "$days" }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            _id: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $limit: 1
    }
])
```